# offline complete satellite map

Tags: vector, image-quality, resource-recommendations, maps

I'm doing computer art with images mixing low zoom areas with high zoom areas automatically. So far, the only images I can use reliably are vector graphics images, since they support infinite zoom without pixellation. Here's an example:

[image: the tiling for your next bathroom renovation]

I warped a vector graphics image consisting of just a simple tiling pattern out to infinity. If I can get a high enough detail image, I should be able to use it to do the same thing without any nasty pixelation. I know there are extremely high detail satellite maps covering the whole world. What I'd like is a massive archive full of such maps that I can use offline to create these images. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Your best bet is probably NASA.  I know they have _tons_ of high-resolution images available.  I've used their resources several times, to get textures and height maps for making 3D models of planets.  I forget exactly where I found all the resources, let me try to find them.

Comment: Why do you not generate it on the fly?  Extreme large images work by sending tiles from a database like google maps. So you never have the entire thing in memory once.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist no need to create a computer-art tag, since what you're asking is more related to obtaining the resources than the art itself.

Comment: @joojaa well, fair enough. But I thought under certain circumstances that may be impractical, since I may be sampling over too many tiles and the only way to get the rendering done in a realistic amount of time may be to just download the whole thing. After some thought though I think it can be done with google maps, but only because it's accessible at different zoom levels. So for this application anyway, I think you're right. It can be done over the internet.

Comment: @Luciano yeah you're right.

Comment: @JohnManly If you can find those images again, I'd be eternally grateful lol.

Answer (score 2):

**Take a look at [Mapbox Satellite](https://www.mapbox.com/satellite/).**

They provide beautiful, high-res satellite imagery and put a lot of effort into merging and cleaning imagery from different sources:

- Imagery from commercial imagery providers, NASA, and USGS
- Cloudless imagery at zoom levels 0-8
- Color-corrected and blended

You can get the imagery *without* any labels (which is good for artwork) and the tiles are downloadable with [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/). In fact, for artistic purposes it might be worthwhile looking at [the different styles](https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/) that can be created with Mapbox Studio.
There is a free starter plan and you can probably contact them about using (some of) the imagery for artwork.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look:

Blue Marble
https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484

I can't remember the link but there is a higher resolution separated in 6 quadrants somewhere in the site.

Bing offers some licenses of usage of Bing Maps:
https://www.microsoft.com/maps/licensing/licensing.aspx